# how to uninstall sublime text3 completely?

Tags: package-management, sublime-text

I installed sublime text3 and 'package manager' also.

In this process, there was an unknown error and the process just stopped.

So I just shut down by force and ran again to complete install.

but in 3seconds, sublime text stopped again and I repeated uninstall - install process.

I think the problem occur when installed package manager ..

so I want to CLEAN UP whole thing about sublime text3 completely and try again.
( I'm new to ubuntu.. so I don't understand why same result is remain after uninstall - reinstall process )

Right now, there is no way to solve no matter how I repeat the process.

please help me!

Comment: What are you using to install these packages? (commands, PPAs, instructions, etc)

Comment: Possibly (not unlikely) local settings file of sublime are corrupted. Please remove `~/.config/sublime-text-3`, log out and in and try again.

Answer (score 2):

uninstall sublime-text-3 using `purge` or `--purge remove` option it will uninstall completely.

if you install sublime-text-installer from [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/sublime-text-3-ubuntu-ppa-now-available.html) then uninstall using

```
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer
```

or 
if you downloaded from [here](http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime-text_build-3083_amd64.deb) then uninstall using command

```
sudo dpkg -P sublime-text
```

then remove dependencies if any using command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then install again if you are getting any problem with your installation method then use this method

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

i have tested this on Ubuntu 14.04 .its working for me .

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.
I tried your solution but it didn't work. ( result was same.. )

But I figured out the way to solve this problem. 
In 'config' folder, there were a package records remained. 
So I moved to that folder and removed that records. 
After this process, sublime text3 installed ordinarily like first time.

Anyway I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @hagfish1210 Please post your solution as an answer, not a comment!