# "enter license" still exists after Sublime Text 3 deletion

Tags: sublime-text, software-uninstall

I installed ST3 but I deleted it using this: [how to uninstall sublime text3 completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674484/how-to-uninstall-sublime-text3-completely). I didn't know it needed a license key. Then I installed ST2 but I couldn't open it because a dialog from ST3 asking for the license key still pops up (and the installation name is ¨Enter license¨). I tried to delete the ST2 "enter license" program (I don't know what it is) but it still exists (icon changed to default)

**installed ST3 using:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

**and deleted using:**

```
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer
```

**installed ST2 using:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Here is the window that opens instead of ST2:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? How did you install Sublime Text 3 originally? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Could you please rename or remove `~/.config/sublime-text-2` and try again? What's the output of `subl`?

Comment: You don not need a key to use Sublime Text 2 or 3. You can evaluate the program for free for... forever. It just sometimes pops up a message box to remind you to buy a key. But you can click those away. And you can safely use version 3 since although it is in beta for years, it is actually very stable.

Answer (score 2):

This can (also) be caused by having added the development branch to your apt sources by mistake, instead of the stable releases.

make sure that

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

contains

```
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
```

and not

```
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/dev/
```

The development branch is only available to licensed users as stated on their wobwob: 
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

"Builds listed in the dev channel are only available to licensed users. Users who are evaluating Sublime Text before purchase will need to use the stable channel."

Answer (score 0):

This update fixed this problem for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3  
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer  
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

source: [How to update Sublime Text Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44561918/8819251)